# NodeJS wait for loop to finish (async / await / promisse)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a loop fetching some info in an API, first I need this loop for to wait for the request to finish and after continue for the next array value, after the loop finish, then I need it to call that function again every 5 seconds, but only after the previous call ends.

Something like this:

```
let ids = [1, 2];

async function getInfoAPI(ids) {

   for (const id of ids){
      const apiInfo = await fetch(`https://apiurl/${id}`);
      const infoJSON = await apiInfo.json();

      //Do more things here
   }
}
```

Now I need to call the function and wait for the loop to finish. After the loop is completed then wait for 5 seconds and call the `getInfoFromAPI` function again. I tried `setInterval` but if the loop, for some reason, takes more than 5 seconds to respond, the `getInfoFromAPI` will be called again even if it didn't finish the previous loop.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
        getInfoAPI(ids);
}, 5000);
```

Is there any way I could do that using promises or something like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Thank @evolutionxbox but that doesn't answer my question. I still need the function to be called again 5 seconds after all process is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function run() {
    getInfo(...).then(() => {
        setTimeout(run, 5000)
    });
}

run().catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Or, I prefer using a promise version of `setTimeout()`.  I the latest version of nodejs, you can use `timersPromises.setTimeout()` and it returns a promise:

```
import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises';

async function run() {
    await getInfo(...)
    await setTimeout(5000);
    return run();
}

run().catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Or, use a `while` loop with `await`:

```
import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises';

async function run() {
    while (true) {
        await getInfo(...)
        await setTimeout(5000);
    }
}

run().catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by importing the promise based `setTimeout` that ships with NodeJs 16+ and using it as follows:

Import:

```
import { setTimeout } from "timers/promises"
```

Use:

```
while (true) {
  await getInfoAPI(ids);
  await setTimeout(5000);
}
```

Comment: The regular `setTimeout()` does not return a promise so `await` won't do anything with it as it returns a `timerID`.  There is a different `setTimeout()` that does return a promise.

Comment: @Binho has tagged this with ```node.js```, and ```setTimeout``` does return a promise when run in that environment.

Comment: No, it does not return a promise in nodejs.  Nodejs doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#settimeoutcallback-delay-args).  It returns a `timerID`.  Your answer could illustrate how to use [timersPromises.setTimeout()](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timerspromisessettimeoutdelay-value-options) instead which is a different version that does support promises.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the use of the ```import { setTimeout } from "timers/promises"```, which does ship with nodejs 16+ https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers-promises-api, I'll update my answer to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion:

```js
async function getInfoPeriodically() {
  await getInfoAPI(ids);
  setTimeout(() => {
    getInfoPeriodically()
  }, 5000);
}
```

You can add the parameters to customize this function/pass values in but this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)? With that you can use concurrency to fetch all the data at once, instead that one by one. In case you need to do it one by one, I suggest you to use [`for-await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of).